# MacBook Pro 2018 13" TB & kernel panic

Tags: macbook-pro, kernel-panic, ventura

My MacBook Pro 13" 2018 TB (has) started to crash randomly with the log message being:

```
CPU Machine Check Architecture Error Dump (CPU: UNKNOWN, CPUID: 0x806EA)
Core: 0 
  IA32_MC1_STATUS=0xFF80000000000184
  IA32_MC1_CTL=0x0
  IA32_MC1_ADDR=0x12C5F0C0
  IA32_MC1_MISC=0x86
```

Any idea what the cause could be?

Comment: More details on what the Mac is doing (or not) when this happens would be handy. As is, your question doesn't give enough information. Any correlations with the kernel panic and your activity when this happens (browsing the 'net, listening to tunes, rendering a huge 3D animated video, compiling code, etc)?

Comment: During all of the mentioned activities, randomly…

Comment: Sounds like a HW problem. Does it happen when the MBP is running on battery alone? Any spills, drops, gamma ray bursts in the vicinity?